# Should addon of any extension use <depends> tag in addon registration file(package1_module2.xml)?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, dependency

One `package1_Module1` extension is created and I want to make its addon of `package1_Module1`.

`<depends>
   <Package1_Module1/>
</depends>`

this above code need in `app/etc/modules/Package1_Module2.xml` for `package1_Module1` extension addon ?

Comment: The question is about how to declare a dependency or about best practices?

Comment: I know if I declare depends tag so addon depended on package extension but I want to know that is it compulsory or need depends code in addon regsitration xml file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set as dependency just those modules that need some code and/or data/attributes created by other modules.

So lets say that the module `My_ModuleA` declare a helper `My_ModuleA_Helper_Data` and Other module `Your_ModuleA` has a helper that extends `My_ModuleA_Helper_Data`, in this case you should declare that dependency.

Another valid case would be if `My_ModuleA` creates a product attribute `custom_sarasa_id` and `My_ModuleB` use that attribute to do some.

**EDIT:** I almost forget... if you don't have any specific data or code dependency but you just need that `My_ModuleA` comes before `MyModuleB` ie: because both are observing the same event, you could use dependency to such order related tasks too.

Based on the examples below you should declare:

> app/etc/modules/My_ModuleA.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_ModuleA>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core/>
                <Mage_Eav/>
                <Mage_Catalog/>
            </depends>
        </My_ModuleA>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/etc/modules/Your_ModuleA.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_ModuleA>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <My_ModuleA/>
            </depends>
        </Your_ModuleA>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/etc/modules/My_ModuleB.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_ModuleB>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <My_ModuleA/>
            </depends>
        </My_ModuleB>
    </modules>
</config>
```